# Actions On Google Implicit Oauth Flow fails...What's wrong?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am implementing my own Oauth server for the implicit oauth flow as defined here 
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2?oauth=implicit

Seems simple enough, after checking the client details, I just need to redirect right? This is where I hit the issue. The documentation says the redirect url must be as follows -

> https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING

Notice the **'#'**.

However, when you redirect to this URL, this seems to weirdly mess up actions on google, after which the "Sign in Helper" intent which we were using earlier momentarily seems to work and then fails. It must be failing, but the console doesn't show any errors
[image: yes, it is going to work!]
[image: but alas no!]

In fact this problem persists, and the only way I have found of removing it is to recreate the project. ( Oh, the pain :/)

However, when I replace the "#" with "?" like a regular query string, after the redirect we get a 400 error -

> The parameter "code" or "error" must be set in the query string.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. For reference this is the JS that constructs the redirect url -

```
//bearerToken already generated at this point in the code
var redirectUri = params.get("redirect_uri");
var state = params.get("state");
var redirectString = redirectUri;
redirectString+="#access_token="+bearerToken;
redirectString+="&token_type=bearer";
redirectString+="&state="+state;
window.location.href=redirectString;
```

Comment: Have you tried making the `access_token` parameter `code`, instead?

Answer (score 0):

They only thing I did different from you which made it work in the end was using `window.location.replace` instead of `window.location.href`.

As I understand it `window.location.replace` is the client-side way to simulate a HTTP Redirect.

My url looked like this `https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/project-id#access_token=4cc355t0k3n&token_type=bearer&state=AB8b_TOEy...`